# SQL Server 2008 won't let me add foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've been using SQL Server for years, so I'm not a noob.  I've recently been having problems where I can't add a foreign key to certain tables in my database using SQL Management Studio and SQL Server 2008 Express.  The table I'm trying to reference is there and it has a primary key (with the primary key constraint created), but it doesn't show up in the list of tables that I can choose from when I'm trying to add the FK.

If I try and add the FK through plain old T-SQL, the query succeeds, but if I view the new FK using the UI, the primary key table dropdown is empty.  The FK is there and it actually does work if I try to insert some data that would violate the constraint.

Anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a tool issue (SSMS), not an engine issue

Thoughts:

- close/reopen SSMS (caching?)
- patched to same version as server install?
- different schema etc?

Edit, after comment and it's SSMS caching:

You can also right-click on the table node and refresh so SSMS updates the cache. This problem goes back to SQL Enterprise Manager and SQL 2000. No known fix after 10 years...

Comment: Closing and reopening SSMS fixed the problem, but it's really annoying to have to do that all the time.

Comment: I have been right-clicking on the table, database, etc. and doing Refresh, that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: FYI, SSMS has *very* sticky caching.  Refreshing usually works  for most stuff, but for whatever reasons, sometimes only restrating works on some things.